# Adding items to List View as cards

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

Populate the `ListView` with Cards, the number of Cards in the `ListView` will be equal to the predefined number in program. So how do we add `CardView` in `ListView` dynamically like that :

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have added list view in activity via xml. Now i want to add CardView to it dynamically. Have done it previously for ListView , but couldn't find any adapter class in cardview. Is there any adapter class in it?

Comment: You will just need to create a Custom Adapter that uses Cardview.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do we add CardView in ListView

You need to create a `CustomListAdapter` with `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`
 as the parent layout of your custom list item.

**To read about how to create a custom list adapter, check [here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html), or Try googling it**

> Then to add list items dynamically to your list.

You need to add the new items to the `ArrayList` feeding the your custom list adapter. Then notify the adapter.

**Suppose** your ArrayList containing your custom items is `myListItems` and your custom list Adapter is `adapter`

```
public void addItems(CustomItem item) {
    myListItems.add(list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You should create an adapter for that list view [adapter docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and add the element in the adapter. then `notifyDataSetChanged();` 
2) You could just add child view to list view but I don't recommend that

Comment: Thanks for responding to this question. Actually i want to add card view dynamically , inside a list view.